# Spaceship on Planet with No Government

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for an old short story I read many years ago about a spaceship that lands on a planet and no local person seems to notice or care about the spacecraft being there. The people are independent and have no government.

Comment: This is a very vague question which is unlikely to be solved. Try to add any details you can to make the question more unique. Take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9337) to see if you can add in any more details.

Comment: This is a pretty common trope. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/849484.Voyage_from_Yesteryear for example.

Answer (score 7):

Although the description is quite vague, you're probably thinking of Eric Frank Russell's classic story "...And Then There Were None".

You can read the full text [here](https://www.abelard.org/e-f-russell.php). Here's an example of the natives ignoring the spaceship:

> Sergeant Gleed did not have to take his men far. They were one hundred yards beyond the ship’s great snout when he noticed a man ambling across the field to his right. Treating the ship with utter indifference, this character was making toward the farmer still toiling far over to the left.
>
> ‘Patrol, right wheel!’ yelled Gleed, swift to take advantage of the situation. The patrol right-wheeled, marched straight past the wayfarer who couldn’t be bothered even to wave a handkerchief at them. Now Gleed ordered an about-turn and followed it with a take-him gesture.
>
> Speeding up its pace, the patrol opened its ranks and became a double file of men tramping on either side of the lone pedestrian. Ignoring his suddenly acquired escort the latter continued to plod straight ahead like one long convinced that all is illusion.

Other things that might jog your memory: the people call themselves "Gands" (from Gandhi) and the interlopers as "Antigands", and they talk about "planting an ob" (obligation) on each other.

Comment: Also "MYOB" (mind your own business) and "Freedom-I won't".